# Homestead - composer global require is trying to find an incorrect package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, homestead

I am trying to install Laravel Homestead, and when I enter the following command:

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

It returns the error "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

However, the error shows `laavel` not `laravel` as I inputted! Why is it autocorrecting to an incorrect spelling? How can I resolve this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This might sound a tad insulting, but did you try writing the line from scratch again? It looks like you're on a Macbook Pro; I know I occasionally type characters that aren't quite the characters they look like on mine, without the OS letting me know. It's absurdly frustrating.

Comment: Hello, yes I did. I have also copied it from the tutorial website, and restarted my computer. I also did `composer dumpautoload` and `composer clearcache`. All of which attempt to search for `Laavel` instead of `Laravel`!

Comment: Sounds like you did everything by the book. Here's hoping you manage to resolve it.

Comment: I hope so too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, I did the following:

`sudo open .composer` and then within `composer.json` I rectified the line which was spelt incorrectly.

For some reason, Composer wasn't picking up Laravel and Laavel are spelt differently?!